# How to completely remove a package from project/solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I made an ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my MVC project. When I did this the EntityFramework package was automatically downloaded and installed into my project via the NuGet package manager.

How do I completely remove this ADO.NET Entity Data Model and its related EntityFramework from my project?

(I am working in Visual Studio Community)

Comment: uninstall nuget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Get-Project -All | Uninstall-Package <package name>
```

If this package have dependencies, you can add option `-RemoveDependencies` in above command line.

Or you can manually do it through the VS GUI,
Right-click your solution `> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`..., switch to the `Install` tab, select the package which you want to uninstall, then you can check the first checkbox, all the check boxes would be selected, click the uninstall button:

Comment: And for the ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my Models Folder, do I just delete those files? I ask these simple questions because I like to be sure I can completely undo my actions.

Comment: Yes sir, even leaving them won't change anything since you have uninstalled it

Comment: I'd suggest to backup them first , then delete!

Comment: @mxmissile sometimes git or svn don't store the changes happening outside the code layer, like packages, custom attributes...